# how can I remove duplicates by row in 2d array c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have an int array which contains ascii code of every letter of words that user enters, than I need to remove dublicates, but its just dont work. I tried sorting and then removing, but I don't even know if it's really neccesary and maybe there is an easier approach.
I want so that my array that contained for example:

```
127, 113, 127, 127, 109, 0, 0, ...;
105, 109, 114, 105, 0, 0, ...;
102, 101, 101, 101, 0, 0, 0, ....;
102, 0, 0, ....;

look like this:
127, 113, 109, 0, 0, ...;
105,109, 114,105, 0, 0, ...;
102, 101, 0, 0, ...;
102, 0, 0, ...;
```

I tried to replace element that is the same as j++ with 0, but it seems to not be working

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 5
#define n 50

int main(void) {
    char arr[N][10] = { 0 };
    int arri[n][n] = { 0 };
    printf("Programm to check if words are anagrams.");
    printf("\nPlease enter your word one by one:\n");
    int y = 0, u = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        scanf("%s", arr[y]);
    }
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0,g=0, num = 0, l = 0, h = 0;
        char *p;
        char *lk;
        int count1 = 0;

        for (;k<N ; l = 0, h++, k++, j = 0, i = 0)
            for (p = &arr[k][j]; *p != '\0'; l++) //convert char into int
            {
                p = &arr[k][j];
                arri[h][i] = int(*p);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        
        for (j = 0;i<n; i++)
        {
            for (;j<n;j++)
            {
                int k = j + 1;
                if (arri[i][j] == arr[i][k] && arri[i][k] != 0)
                {
                    arri[i][k] = 0; // not chaning the same element with 0
                }
                
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Clarification: Comment in code suggests you'll be trying to find 'anagrams'. `desserts` and `stressed` are anagrams, but `desert` and `stressed` are not. If you strip out duplicate letters, you'll be finding incorrect results.

Comment: `scanf("%s", arr[y]);` risks undefined behavior due to buffer overflow.  Use `scanf("%9s", arr[y]);`.

Answer (score 0):

OP variables used: `y`, `u`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `g`, `num`, `l`, `h`, `p`, `lk`, `count1`

Can anyone see a problem with this?

Keep things simple. The following 'compacts' an array (a C string benefiting from the trailing `'\0'`) into itself, removing 2nd and subsequent occurrences of any character. Apart from the array itself, this involves only two variables: `'i'` & `'j'`.

The *trick* is to realise that, when considered alone, the 0th character is obviously the 1st occurrence of that character. The first nested loops scan for subsequent occurrences of each character in the string. Those 'duplicates' are replaced with copies of the 0th character. The second loop merely 'compacts-out' all of those duplications of the 0th character.

```
int main( void ) {
    char arr[] = "nn-n-ow is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party";

    puts( arr );
    int i, j;
    for( i = 1; arr[i]; i++ )
        for( j = i+1; arr[j]; j++ )
            if( arr[j] == arr[i] ) // repeat?
                arr[j] = arr[0];   // replace!
    for( i = 1, j = 1; arr[j]; j++ )
        if( arr[j] != arr[0] )
            arr[i++] = arr[j]; // compact
    arr[i] = '\0'; // terminate
    puts( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

```
nn-n-ow is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party
n-ow isthemfralgdcpy
```

Note: This is for demonstration purposes. A `unsigned char *` pointer could be defined to *stand-in* for the literal `arr[]` to deal with these 1 byte integer values if desired. For this demo, a C string of ASCII characters was the most convenient representation.

A trivial optimisation would be to 'skip over' instances of the 0th character during the scan and not continue to scan for more occurrences. (ie: the outer loop could 'short cut' to avoid running the inner loop.)